# trying to redirect the php page is get id is empty ir does not exists

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?
include.....
if ($picid != $_GET['picid']) || (empty($picid)) { echo "page not working";

}
else {
$picid = $_GET['picid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pic_info WHERE picid = 'picid1' ");// problem

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)):
$picid = $rows['picid'];
$title = $rows['title'];
$link = $rows['link'];
$description = $rows['description'];
$movie_pic = $rows['movie_pic'];
$source = $rows['source'];

}

$get_comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE picid ='$picid'");// work partially
$comment_count = mysql_num_rows($get_comment);
if ($comment_count>0)
{ messages = " ";
while ($com = mysql_fetch_array($get_comment)){
$comment_id = $com['comment_id'];
$name = $com['name'];
$message = $com['message'];
$time_post= $com['time_post'];
$messages .= '<em> on ' .$time_post.'</em><b>   '.$name.'   said.....</b><br/> '.$message.'<hr/>';  // line with problem
}
}
?>
```

i am stuck i am trying to say that if `$_GET['picid'];` is empty echo out error message or if the movid does not exist in the db echo out error message. when i run it i get an error. not sure if i am calling the correct function. what am i doing wrong please help

Answer (score 0):

I have this method defined:

```
function not_empty($var) {
    return isset($var) && $var != "";
}
```

And so either !not_empty or:

```
function is_empty($var) {
    return !not_empty($var);
}
```

I also noticed that you have:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)):
```

but there is no corresponding:

```
endwhile;
```

Maybe stick with either braces or the colon just in case.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Also, you could try to use

```
<?php
// code
?>
```

rather than short tags.

And you're missing a bracket here:

```
if ( $picid != $_GET['picid']) || (empty($picid) ) {
```

should be:

```
if ( ($picid != $_GET['picid']) || (empty($picid) ) {
```

And of course you would have:

```
include("somefile");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your asking to check if there is an anything set for the GET variable picid and if not return an error.

```
if (!isset($_GET[picid]) { 
    return "No Pic Id" 
} else { 
"run db code..."
}
```